# How to change CSS properties of an active item when slide loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap carousel with id myCarousel.

The Carousel has a set fixed height with a javascript function setCarouselSizeStatic and the image gets centered with CSS below.

I have one smaller picture which has a lot less height hence it is floating to the top. I want the picture to be stuck to the bottom while still centered horizontally.

I want before the next slide is loaded to change the margin top of the picture to equal CarauselHeight - imgeHeight.

My question is how to achieve this?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="Image" src="http://somewhere.image1.jpg" alt="Image from google">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="item">
      <img class="Image" src="http://somewhere.image2.jpg" alt="Image from google">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="Image" src="http://somewhere.image3.jpg" alt="Image from google">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

CSS which centers the image:

```
.carousel-inner > .item> img {
    margin: 0 Auto;
}
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#myCarousel').carousel();
     setCarauselSizeStatic();
});

//The purpose of this function is to make the carousel the same size 
//for other images than the first without breaking responsivness
//as my first image is the biggest it all makes sense


$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  //get the width of the image loaded
  var imageHeight = $('.active').height();

  //get the width of the carausel
  var carHeight = $('#myCarousel').height();

  //calculate the margin
  var margin = carHeight - imageHeight;

  //make the top margin of the item equal to CarouselHeight - imageHeight
  $(".active").css("margin", margin );
});

function setCarauselSizeStatic() {
  $("#myCarousel").css("height", $('#myCarousel').height()
  )};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following jQuery code for your fix:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#myCarousel').carousel();
 setCarauselSizeStatic();
});
//declare 2 global variables.
var currentSlideHeight;
var maxSlideHeight;

$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
//set the heigth of the previous image loaded for next slide
currentSlideHeight = $('#myCarousel').height();
});

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
//set the heigth of the current image loaded and presume its the max height image 
maxSlideHeight = $('#myCarousel').height();

// check if the maxSlideHeight is really the maximum.
if(maxSlideHeight < currentSlideHeight)
{
  // set new max slide height
  maxSlideHeight = currentSlideHeight;

  //set the carousel inner box height to the max height found till now
  setCarauselSizeStatic(maxSlideHeight);

  //for the margin adjust to show lower height images at the bottom of the carousel
  //calculate the margin of the margin difference by subtracting the lower height image value from carousel height
  var margin = maxSlideHeight - $('.active .Image').height();

  // get the current active item margin-top value
  var currentMargin = $(".active").css("margin-top");

  // check if the margin adjust not already applied to avoid re running code again and again.
  if(currentMargin != margin)
    {
        //set the margin-top of the item to the adjustment calculated
        $(".active").css("margin-top", margin );  
    }
 }
});

//The purpose of this function is to make the carousel the same size  
function setCarauselSizeStatic() {
   $(".carousel-inner").css("height", $('#myCarousel').height())
};

function setCarauselSizeStatic(customheight) {
   $(".carousel-inner").css("height", customheight)
};
```

**[Explaination]**

As you don't have a fixed height of the carousel. You needed a dynamic way to find the largest image in the carousel. To do that we declared 2 global variables and also add in the slid.bs.carousel event which occurs right after the slide has happened. Also i added an overloaded method of the setCarauselSizeStatic to take height parameter and set it. I think the rest the comments in the above jQuery code will explain what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work as well. The proble may be with the .active? Is class active given to the element that is loaded to the carousel? or maybe CSS function? How does the CSS jquery function know that margin is px?

Comment: It is working for me here : http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/edqpQm . unless i misunderstood your requirement. One thing i would like to mention. You need to set a fixed height for a carousel for images as the carousel will automatically adjust itself to the image size if not set. So if you set the height then you wont all this need this jquery except the height margin adjusting line and just work with css to accomplish this task.